# rails server command is not working on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, server

After creating my first application using rails, I tried to run the server using

```
rails server
```

However I an output totally different from what I expect 
[image]
[image: the output that I get after running the rails server command]

What might be the problem?

Comment: Can you post the beginning of the error message. You only posted the bottom portion.

Comment: I re edited my question showing the very beginning of what I get as an error. I hope that helps.